# SSL Handshake error caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, ssl, jdbc, sslhandshakeexception

I have a Spring-Boot web application that accesses a MySQL database. I am trying to encrypt this access using SSL. For this purpose, I have followed a tutorial at https://www.techrunnr.com/connect-mysql-server-from-spring-boot-application-with-ssl/.
However, when I try to access the database, I am getting `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure` which is ultimately caused by `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors`.

The complete stack trace from the IDE is:

```
2020-09-04 11:09:29.227  INFO 17540 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-04 11:09:29.377  INFO 17540 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-09-04 11:09:30.165  INFO 17540 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https) with context path ''
2020-09-04 11:09:30.167  INFO 17540 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-09-04 11:09:30.167  INFO 17540 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-09-04 11:09:30.175  INFO 17540 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.s.SpringbootHibernateApplication     : Started SpringbootHibernateApplication in 3.377 seconds (JVM running for 4.19)
2020-09-04 11:09:30.776 ERROR 17540 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:334) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:164) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1215) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1475) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1381) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1442) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1324) ~[na:na]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:393) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 55 common frames omitted

2020-09-04 11:09:30.777  WARN 17540 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-09-04 11:09:30.786  INFO 17540 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2020-09-04 11:09:31.271  INFO 17540 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-09-04 11:09:32.436 ERROR 17540 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:316) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:334) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:164) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1342) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1215) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:423) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1475) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1381) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:441) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:325) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:400) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1442) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1324) ~[na:na]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:158) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:393) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2020-09-04 11:09:32.437  WARN 17540 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2020-09-04 11:09:32.437 ERROR 17540 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

The status information from the MySQL server is:

```
Connection id:          582
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.21 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 9 days 19 hours 42 min 45 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 6985  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 669  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 583  Queries per second avg: 0.008
--------------
```

The application.properties file:

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc?\
  verifyServerCertificate=true&\
  useSSL=true&\
  requireSSL=true&\
  clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:D:\\BITS\\Practice-School-2\\Training\\Coding projects\\springboot-Hibernate\\src\\main\\resources\\clientkeystore.jks\
  &clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=nucleus&\
  trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:D:\\BITS\\Practice-School-2\\Training\\Coding projects\\springboot-Hibernate\\src\\main\\resources\\truststore.jks\
  &trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=nucleus
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=nucleus
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:medium.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=pkcs12
server.ssl.key-store-password=nucleus
server.ssl.key-password=nucleus
server.ssl.key-alias=medium
server.port=8080
```

Please help me figure out how to remove the above-mentioned exceptions.

Note: when I remove the part

````
  verifyServerCertificate=true&\
  useSSL=true&\
  requireSSL=true&\
  clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:D:\\BITS\\Practice-School-2\\Training\\Coding projects\\springboot-Hibernate\\src\\main\\resources\\clientkeystore.jks\
  &clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=nucleus&\
  trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:D:\\BITS\\Practice-School-2\\Training\\Coding projects\\springboot-Hibernate\\src\\main\\resources\\truststore.jks\
  &trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=nucleus ```

from the application.properties file, the application runs perfectly.
````

Answer (score -1):

useSSl=false will avoid this problem try it

or if you have to use ssl then try this document upto step 10 for enabling ssl in mysql
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/68098

Comment: what does useSSL=false do? when he wanted to use the ssl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).